# How to provide flexible horizontal space between the UI buttons via storyboard in XCode 6.1

Tags: storyboard, autolayout, constraints, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I am creating app which should work on all the four types of iPhone i.e., iPhone 4,5,6 and 6+.
I have created one view as follows and I want to achieve the second view.

**iPhone 5**

[image]

**Second View (iPhone 6)**

[image]

Now I want to have fixed distance between the image and its corresponding count but equidistant among all the four sets of image and its count.
I tried by reducing the priority but that didn't work for me as I would be putting wrong constraints so please let me know how it can be achieved via storyboard.

Comment: Have you resolve this issue yet ?

Comment: I have taken four views and added the image and count on them and fixed the space among them and made their width flexible!

Comment: Can you please share this as a example ?

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by following the below steps:

1. Rather than directly adding the images and count on the main view, I took four separate views for for each set as I have shown by box with black border.
2. After that I added the four sets of image and count label on each view.
3. Put them at the center of their corresponding super view (box with black border)
4. Now I fix the distances between the boxes as shown by Blue color
5. And made their width flexible.
6. The priority of Blue space will be greater than the priority of the widths of the boxes.

   [image]

And I got something like this

[image]

Comment: Hi,I have tried this solution ,but unable to produce the exact result I want.Please elaborate more if possible.Thanks

Comment: Please see this link for my problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665931/flexible-horizontal-spacing-between-ui-labels

Comment: Can you send me your storyboard, I will put the constraints and send back to you