# Flexible horizontal spacing between ui labels

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

I am using auto layout in storyboard with all resolution support,but I am stuck on one thing that.I want flexible horizontal spacing between my labels using constraints.Please see screenshot for more details.
This is a 4.7inch screen.This screen is correct as I designed for particularly this screen[image: [This is a 4.7inch screen.This screen is correct as I designed for particularly this screen]

4 inch screen[image: this is a 4inch screen]

5.5 inch [image: this is a 5.5inch screen]

IPad screen[image: this is iPad screen]

Please help to manage my labels spacing equally in all supported resolutions with auto layout and constraints.

**Edit**

This is my view hierarchy and it is also a subview of some view controller's view.
[image: This is my view hierarchy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 5 views containing labels. Let's call those `view1` through `view5` and let's call their super view `orangeView`.

1. Start by laying out the `orangeView`.  Constrain its leading edge to the leading edge of its super view.  Constrain its trailing edge to the trailing edge of its super view.  Constrain its height to 50.
2. Add 5 more views as subviews of `orangeView`.  Lay them out visually approximately as you want them to be.
3. Starting with the leftmost view, which we'll call `view1`, constrain its top edge to be 8 points from the top edge of it nearest neighbor (which is the `orangeView`'s top).  Constrain its bottom edge to 8 points from the bottom edge of `orangeView`.  Constrain its left edge to be 8 points from its nearest neighbor.  Repeat this for views `2` through `4`, always constraining their top, left, and bottom edges to be 8 points from the nearest neighbor.  For `view5`, constrain all 4 edges to be  8 points from the nearest neighbor.
4. Constrain `view2`'s width to be equal to `view1`'s width.  Constrain `view3`'s width to be equal to `view2`'s width.  Constrain `view4`'s width to be equal to `view3`'s width.  Constrain `view5`'s width to be equal to `view4`'s width.  This is what enables all of the views to grow together in size.
5. Add a label as a subview to each of views `view1` through `view5`.  Constrain their widths and heights to be big enough to hold your text.  Add 2 constraints to each label to center it vertically and horizontally in its containing view.